# Removing created by me sticker set in Telegram (for every user)

Tags: telegram

How to remove telegram sticker set so that we wouldn't be able to find it here: https://t.me/addstickers/lala_by_ibodi_bot. I am the owner of the stickers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use @Stickers Bot, all you need to do is type /delpack and follow the directions from there.